# Regex, match varying number of sets

Tags: c#, regex

I have a program looking to capture formatted string input. The input looks something like

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
```

Where there can be a varying number of numbers as long as they are all inside the set. For instance:

```
{1, 2, 3}
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Would all be valid. However, I need to be able to access each number within that set. I have the following code

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"\{(\d,\s)*(\d)\}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (match.Success)
{
    String s;

    for(int i = 0; i < match.Groups.Count; i++)
    {
        s = match.Groups[i].Value;
        // Do actions here
    }
}
```

Which matches fine, however, I can only access the last and next-to-last number within the set. I would like to be able to read the values from each member of the set. How would I go about doing this? Would something other than regex work better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would something other than regex work better?

While a regex would be most helpful for capturing the brace-enclosed strings, it would be easier after you get that to use simple imperative code to get the numbers within.

I would start with the regex `\{([^\}]*)\}` to grab the inner part of any string starting with '{' and ending with '}' (with no '}' in between).  You can then process the capture using a split by commas to get the numbers within, trimming for whitespace afterwards if needed.

Comment: This is an approach that is probably simpler to understand, after all regexes are notoriously hard to read. However it would also lead to more complex code since you would have to separately validate that each item between commas is actually a number.  *Possibly* it is also less efficient although this would have to be verified of course.

Comment: We're assuming that the input is integers, at least for now thankfully. This worked beautifully, didn't know that C# came with a `split()` function, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should access the `Captures` property of the `Group` to access all captures.

```
for (int i = 0; i < match.Groups.Count; i++)
{
   CaptureCollection caps = match.Groups[i].Captures;
   foreach (Capture cap in caps)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(cap.Value);
   }
}
```

In addition, you might want to change your regex to for example `"\{(\d)(?:,\s(\d))*\}"` if you don't want the comma sign to be part of your captures and you want to also allow a set of only one number.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var Input = "{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} foo {1, 2, 3} baa {1, 2, 3, 4} abc";
var Pattern = "\\{([0-9, ]+)\\}";
var Matches = Regex.Matches(Input, Pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
foreach (Match match in Matches)
{
    string s = match.Groups[1].Value; // n1,n2,n3.. 
     //do actions here 

    /* 
     * if you need parse each element,use s.Split(',').
     * For example 
     *      s is '1,2,3' 
     *      string[] parts = s.Split(',');
     *      for(int x = 0,max = parts.Length; x < max; x++) {
     *          Console.WriteLine(parts[x]);
     *      }
     *      
     *      the output is something like:
     *      1
     *      2
     *      3
     */

}
```